# Same SQL Query Shows Different Results in Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a SQL function that returns an AR Table called ARTable(). While testing this function, I have noticed that the query returns two different results when I run ARTable(GETDATE()) and when I copy and paste the body of the query. The total AR among the different companies is the same, but the aging buckets are different.

Here is my function:

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ARTable]    Script Date: 1/9/2020 5:29:40 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ARTable] (@inputdate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(YEAR(@inputdate), 'D'), datepart(dayofyear, @inputdate)) AS 'Time',
    SUM(invc.Balance) AS 'Value', 
    CASE WHEN invc.DueDate>=@inputDate THEN 'ARC' WHEN invc.DueDate<@inputDate AND DATEADD(day,15,invc.DueDate)>=@inputDate THEN 'AR115' 
    WHEN DATEADD(day,15,invc.DueDate)<@inputDate AND DATEADD(day,30,invc.DueDate)>=@inputDate THEN 'AR1530'
    WHEN DATEADD(day,30,invc.DueDate)<@inputDate AND DATEADD(day,60,invc.DueDate)>=@inputDate THEN 'AR3060'
    WHEN DATEADD(day,60,invc.DueDate)<@inputDate AND DATEADD(day,90,invc.DueDate)>=@inputDate THEN 'AR6090'
    WHEN DATEADD(day,90,invc.DueDate)<@inputDate THEN 'AR90' END AS 'Bucket', invc.company  
    FROM invc LEFT JOIN cus ON cus.cusID=invc.cusID AND cus.company=invc.company 
    WHERE invc.status <> 9 AND invc.status <> 5 AND cus.Category <> 3 AND invc.DueDate IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(invc.date)>=2013 AND invc.creatDat<=@inputdate AND (invc.company <>400 OR (cus.Category<>5 AND cus.kundkategorikod<>7))
    GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN invc.DueDate>=@inputDate THEN 'ARC' WHEN invc.DueDate<@inputDate AND DATEADD(day,15,invc.DueDate)>=@inputDate THEN 'AR115' 
    WHEN DATEADD(day,15,invc.DueDate)<@inputDate AND DATEADD(day,30,invc.DueDate)>=@inputDate THEN 'AR1530'
    WHEN DATEADD(day,30,invc.DueDate)<@inputDate AND DATEADD(day,60,invc.DueDate)>=@inputDate THEN 'AR3060'
    WHEN DATEADD(day,60,invc.DueDate)<@inputDate AND DATEADD(day,90,invc.DueDate)>=@inputDate THEN 'AR6090'
    WHEN DATEADD(day,90,invc.DueDate)<@inputDate THEN 'AR90' END, invc.company
);
```

When I run the function it gives me a result that looks fine. However, when I copy and paste that exact body of the function and find/replace @inputDate with GETDATE() the result is different from when I run ARTable(GETDATE()). It has me stumped. Does anyone know why this is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be a timezone issue.  The date on the server may not be the date you are passing in.

Comment: What happens, where you put GETDATE() if you change it to CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), i believe it is a time related issue. The function is casting the parameter as a date and you are passing a datetime by doing GETDATE().

Comment: Can you show how you call the function?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I just use "SELECT * from Database.dbo.ARTable(GETDATE())"

Comment: Have you checked Gordon's and arahman's suggestions?

Comment: @arahman I tried it with CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE()) and now it's the same! The due date in the invoice table that I'm comparing GETDATE() to is a datetime data type, so if I want to make it accurate I should change the inputdate parameter in the function to be a DATETIME datatype instead of DATE correct?

Comment: @Skwidman396 it all depends on what you want to bring forward as you are using this date logic in your where clause as a filter. If you want the date logic to count from todays date and the current time you would use datetime, if you don't care about the time but you only care about things that happened to do with that date, then you use date. All depends on your use case.

Comment: @Skwidman396 I thought you said the function is fine though? It already casts to date whatever you pass in and provides the correct result right, so in this case you wouldn't need to do anything aslong as your function is providing the correct information for whatever date you are passing. So currently when you call the function and pass getdate() it just strips off the time/makes it midnight and only looks at the date.

Comment: @arahman Well I wasn't sure which one was "correct" because I didn't know why they were different. But now that I know why they were different the DATETIME is what I want instead of the DATE. Thanks! How do you close questions?